# Multiply two matrix by columns with python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrix:

```
A = [a11 a12 

     a21 a22]


B = [b11 b12
     b21 b22]
```

And I want to multiply all its columns (without loops) in order to obtain the matrix:

```
C =[a11*b11   a11*b12   a12*b11   a12*b12
    a21*b21   a21*b22   a22*b21   a22*b22]
```

I've tried with

```
>>> C = np.prod(A,B,axis=0)
```

but prod doesn't accept two input matrix. Neither np.matrix.prod.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution -

```
(A[...,None]*B[:,None]).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)
```

**Philosophy :** In terms of vectorized/broadcasting language, I would describe this as *spreading* or putting the second dimension of the input arrays against each other, while keeping their first dimensions aligned. This spreading is done by introducing new axes with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) for these two inputs and then simply multiplying each other.

**Mathematical view :** Let's use a bit more mathematical view of it with the help of a generic example. Consider input arrays having different number of columns -

```
In [504]: A = np.random.rand(2,3)

In [505]: B = np.random.rand(2,4)
```

First off, extend the dimensions and check their shapes -

```
In [506]: A[...,None].shape
Out[506]: (2, 3, 1)

In [507]: B[:,None].shape
Out[507]: (2, 1, 4)
```

Now, perform the element-wise multiplication, which will perform these multiplications in a broadcasted manner. Take a closer look at the output's shape -

```
In [508]: (A[...,None]*B[:,None]).shape
Out[508]: (2, 3, 4)
```

So, the singleton dimensions (dimension with length = 1) introduced by the use of `None/np.newaxis` would be the ones along which elements of the respective arrays would be broadcasted under the hood before being multiplied. This under-the-hood broadcasting paired with the respective operation (multiplication in this case) is done in a very efficient manner.

Finally, we reshape this `3D` array to `2D` keeping the number of rows same as that of the original inputs.

**Sample run :**

```
In [494]: A
Out[494]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [495]: B
Out[495]: 
array([[12, 13],
       [14, 15]])

In [496]: (A[...,None]*B[:,None]).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)
Out[496]: 
array([[24, 26, 36, 39],
       [56, 60, 70, 75]])
```

**`NumPy matrix` type as inputs**

For [`NumPy matrix types`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) as the inputs, we could use [`np.asmatrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html) that would simply create view into the inputs. Using those views, the broadcasted element-wise multiplication would be performed, finally resulting in a `2D` array after the reshaping. So, the last step would be to convert back to `np.matrix` type. Let's use the same sample inputs to demonstrate the implementation -

```
In [553]: A
Out[553]: 
matrix([[2, 3],
        [4, 5]])

In [554]: B
Out[554]: 
matrix([[12, 13],
        [14, 15]])

In [555]: arrA = np.asarray(A)

In [556]: arrB = np.asarray(B)

In [557]: np.asmatrix((arrA[...,None]*arrB[:,None]).reshape(A.shape[0],-1))
Out[557]: 
matrix([[24, 26, 36, 39],
        [56, 60, 70, 75]])
```

Comment: curious, but when defining the above 2D matrices with `np.matrix()` and applying broadcasting - gives an error `ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Well I was assuming NumPy arrays. Maybe I should clarify on it.

Comment: @Divakar, I just read the first OP's sentence `I have two matrix:` and therefore started with `np.matrix([[11, 12], [21, 22]])` but got an error when testing your approach. Anyway, its probably another case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added modifications needed to make it work for NumPy matrix type inputs.

Comment: @Divakar Is it also possible to do this for more than 2 arrays/matrices?

Answer (score 1):

```
b = np.tile(B, 2) # two copies of B, side by side
a = np.tile(A, 2)
a = np.hstack((a[:,::2], a[:,1::2])) # change 1,2,1,2 to 1,1,2,2
a * b # done
```

I expect there is a better way to do the third step, but the above works and is relatively efficient.

Comment: Is it also possible to do this for more than 2 arrays/matrices?

Comment: @Varlor: Try it, and if you can't figure it out, ask a new question and link to it here.