# Vectorized calculation of scaled/rotated pairwise squared euclidean distance

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Given a set of *n* vectors of dimension *d* stored in a *(n,d)* array and a second set of *m* vectors of the same dimension (stored in *(m,d)* array) I want to calculate the squared point wise distance between the vectors, scaled by some matrix A with the size *(d,d)*.

The output should be a *(n,m)* array.

I expect the input range to be somewhere between 1 to 10.000 for *m* and *n* and 1 to 100 for *d*.

The distance between two points is given by:

[image: d_i_j = (v1_i - v2_j)^T A (v1_i - v2_j)]

In the non-optimized, but working python code this looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array([[1, 2],
               [3, 4],
               [4, 5]])

v2 = np.array([[1,1],
               [2, 2],
               [2, 2],
               [0, 0]])

A = np.array([[1,0], [2, 3]])

d = np.zeros((3, 4))

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,4):
        d[i,j] = (v1[i,:] - v2[j,:]).T @ A @ (v1[i,:] - v2[j,:])
```

The squared distance between the example points is:

```py
d = [[  3.   1.   1.  17.]
 [ 43.  17.  17.  81.]
 [ 81.  43.  43. 131.]]
```

Is there a version of this, that avoids the nested loop in python e.g. using broadcasting black magic?

EDIT:

For the case

```
A = np.array([[1,0], [0, 1]])
```

this is the normal squared euclidean distance which can be calculated e.g.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

cdist(v1,v2,'sqeuclidean')
```

Comment: Can you not just use `dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)` to find the difference in distances between two matrices? Or even the `dot` product?

Comment: I do not know how, hence the question. See edit for clarification

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the distance between `v1` and `v2` or `A` and `d`

Comment: The distance between 'v1' and 'v2', but *scaled* I will add the formula to the question.

Comment: What's the typical value of the number of columns in the inputs?

Comment: What about the values of `m` and `n`?

Comment: I added the information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
V = v1[:,None,:]-v2
d_out = np.einsum('ijk,kl,ijl->ij',V,A,V)
```

Also, play around with the `optimize` flag in `np.einsum` by setting it as `True` to use BLAS.

**Explanation on the vectorized method**

Original code was -

```
d[i,j] = (v1[i,:] - v2[j,:]).T @ A @ (v1[i,:] - v2[j,:])
```

I. We are translating :

```
v1[i,:] - v2[j,:]
```

to the outer operation with `broadcasting` :

```
v1[:,None,:]-v2
```

Schematically put :

```
v1[:,None,:]  :  m x 1 x n
v2            :      m x n
output, V     :  m x m x n
```

[More info on `outer` explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55832719/)

More info on `broadcasting` could be found in [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

II. Next up, `(v1[i,:] - v2[j,:]).T @ A @ (v1[i,:] - v2[j,:])` with the new `V` becomes `np.einsum('ijk,kl,ijl->ij',V,A,V)` using `einsum`'s string notation. More info could be found in [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

Comment: Wow, a speedup of at least two orders of magnitude for me! Thank you!
Can you explain how this works? Or can you point me to a resource that explains einsum in addition to the docs you linked?

Comment: @AlexbGoode Added some comments.